# ionic 3 native google-maps and native firebase plugins it does not fail together in the app

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, maps

when I install these two plugins in the same app do not work on the device, I installed the plugins separately and they work, I have changed versions and still fail, any ideas?

cordova   7.0.1
ionic  3.20.0

package.json
"cordova-plugin-firebase": "^0.1.25",
"cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "^2.2.9",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better build apk or for device with ionic cordova platform add android and using android studio.

platform android - app - build.gradle  .. try change

```html
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib"))
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:11.8.0"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8.0"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0"
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:24.1.0"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:26.+"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3+"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

and in platforms -> android -> cordova-plugin-firebase

```html
dependencies {
    compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.4@aar'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
}
```

in package,json

```html
"dependencies": {
"cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "^2.2.8",
"cordova-plugin-firebase": "^0.1.25",
},
"cordova": {
  "plugins": {
    "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": {
      "API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID": "API MAP ANDROID",
      "API_KEY_FOR_IOS": "API MAP IOS"
      },
  }
}
```

API MAP ANDROID https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup?hl=id

API MAP IOS 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/get-api-key